# Two-way binding with checkboxes always returns "on"

Tags: javascript, data-binding, reactjs

I'm trying to reproduce a simple two-way binding example in the React.js framework by following this official tutorial: ["Two-Way Binding Helpers"](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

I created a "MyCheckbox" component that looks like this:

```
var MyCheckbox = React.createClass({

    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            fieldname: '',
            value: this.props.value
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        var valueLink = this.linkState('value');
        var me = this;
        var handleChange = function (e) {
            valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value === 'on');
        };

        return React.DOM.input({
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: valueLink.value,
            onChange: handleChange,
        });
    }

});
```

"MyCheckbox" is rendered the following way:

```
React.renderComponent(MyCheckbox({
    value: false
}), document.body);
```

When rendering the first time, everything works as expected, if the value is `true`, the checkbox will be checked, if the value is `false` then it will not.

If you initialise the checkbox as being unchecked and then check it, everything works fine.

- The issues it that when clicking the checkbox to uncheck it, `e.target.value` is always 'on'.
- I also wanted to ask what differences are there between the [ReactLink Without LinkedStateMixin](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-without-linkedstatemixin) and [ReactLink Without valueLink](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-without-valuelink) methods of data-binding ?

Any ideas ?

I use the latest React.js version (`v0.10.0`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The "value" property on a checkbox is fixed, in the old days it was the value that was submitted along with the form *only if* the checkbox was checked.

The quick fix is this instead:

```
valueLink.requestChange(e.target.checked);
```

The valueLink only works when it is the value of the input that changes. Turns out that to link to the checked property, the checkedLink needs to be used instead:

```
render: function () {
    return React.DOM.div(null, [
        React.DOM.input({
            type: 'checkbox',
            checkedLink: this.linkState('value'),
        }),
        React.DOM.span(null, "state: " + this.state.value)
    ]);
}
```

Seems a shame that the valueLink can't be used for both!

Comment: Have a look at checkedLink instead of valueLink too, that seems to work. I can't find a reference to checkedLink in the docs, but it is in the [release notes](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/02/16/react-v0.9-rc1.html)

Comment: That worked great thanks ! Regarding my second question, could you tell me what the differences are between the "without valueLink" and "without LinkedStateMixin" binding methods ?

Comment: Magic, good to hear. Those examples are making the point that the "two-way binding" helpers are not special, that they are just a shorthand for setting up onChange and setState. It is also trying to show how the two sides (getting the values out of the DOM elements, and setting the state on the React component) are independent, so you can use the shorthand for one or the other or both. My answer above is an example of that too, I've changed from using the valueLink to using checkedLink, while still using the same linkState helper.

Comment: This will be better documented in the next React's release: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1952

Comment: I have a similar problem not using valueLink, just change handler, after update (where new bound checked value is false) the checkbox is still checked.  The DOM has changed (now checked property) but the checkbox still has check?  is there a way to force control to update?

Comment: Note: the two way binding handlers are now depricated: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution using state:

```
  constructor(props) { // list of objects
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      is_checked: false
    };
  }

  toggleCheckbox(event) {
    let newValue = (this.state.is_checked === "on" || this.state.is_checked === true) ? false : true;
    this.setState({
      is_checked: newValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.is_checked}
          onChange={this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```